# How to upgrade from Rails 5.1 to Rails 6.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The title sums it up pretty much.

I want to do it via the console using the `bundler. There are several changes on the way rails has handled things such as the frontend. More details over [here](https://naildrivin5.com/blog/2016/05/17/announcing-rails-6-an-imagined-roadmap.html).

Will I have to rewrite frontend of my app again? Will it be enough to just update the bins and executables manually? Or run `$ rails app:update` to overwrite old stuff.

Comment: The title of that article is: "Announcing Rails 6: An *Imagined* Keynote" (emphasis added).

Comment: Here's a guide. https://www.alexpapworth.co.uk/guide/how-to-upgrade-to-rails-6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it may have been a joke back when you originally posted this question, but Rails 6.0.0 is now a reality! [Released Aug. 15, 2019](https://rubyonrails.org/). I would recommend running `gem update rails` as a first try, but "updating" to Rails 6 was not so easy for my Windows 10 system.

If you used railsinstaller.org to install Rails previously, you will not be able to install Rails 6 with it - or update - at the time of this writing. In order to update to Rails 6 you *must* be running ruby 2.4.4 or greater, but railsinstaller.org is limited to ruby 2.3 max. Check your version with `ruby -v`. I used [this tutorial](https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/how-to-install-rubyonrails-on-windows-7-8-10-complete-tutorial-2017-fc95720ee059) to do a fresh install of Ruby 2.6 and Rails 6 while updating gem to 3.0.

I would recommend installing everything fresh so you know where all of your dependencies are and how they work. It will also be **much** easier to update each individual component this way -- unless you opt to use tools like [rvm](https://rvm.io/), which by nature will be easier.

If you're having issues and want a fresh install of the latest Ruby and Rails, read the article I linked :) I only posted this answer because I know railsinstaller.org was recommended to a lot of people (like me) as an easy install method back when it was being maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version — Rails 5.1.5 released February 14, 2018 .

Rails 6 is NOT released !! And if it was the case bundler should make it clean

Comment: > And if it was the case bundler should make it clean… except it usually doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The post you linked is just a joke. Anyway, Rails 6 is under development (since January 30 I believe). Just wait.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/version.rb

[image]

Comment: The question will become relevant in due course of time. The joke is frankly on me. 〰

Answer (score 1):

Just run on your terminal:

```
gem update rails
```

That worked for me.